# "Class 'App\Controllers\controller' not found"

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel here i am trying to make my own login and registration form where user can login and register,My registration forms works fine it collects the data and stores it in a database,But whenever i try to login using the same data it gives me this error.Any help would be appreciated i have tried many ways but failed.
Thanks....

Error:
Class 'App\Controllers\controller' not found

MY HTML:

```
@extends("layouts.master")

@section('title')
My page
@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<h3>Sign-Up</h3>
<form action="{{route('signup')}}" method="post">

<div class="form-group">
<label for="email">Your email</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="first_name">First Name</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input class="form-control"  type="password" name="password" id="password">
</div>

<button type="sumbit" class="btn btn-primary">sumbit</button>
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">

</form>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<h3>Login </h3>
<form action="{{route('signin')}}" method="post">

<div class="form-group">
<label for="email">Your email</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input class="form-control"  type="password" name="password" id="password">
</div>

<button type="sumbit" class="btn btn-primary">sumbit</button>
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">

</form>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

CONTROLLER:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;
use App\UserTypes;

use Auth;
use Hashids;
use Redirect;
use Request;
use Hash;



class UserController extends controller
{
    public function getdashboard()
    {
        return view('dashboard');
    }

    public function postSignUp(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request['email'];
        $first_name = $request['first_name'];
        $password = bcrypt($request['password']);


        $user = new User();
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->first_name = $first_name;
        $user->password = $password;

        $user->save();
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
    public function postSignIn(Request $request)
    {
        if(Auth::attempt([ 'email' => $request['email'],'password' => $request['password']])){
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

ROUTE:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::post('/signup',[
    'uses'=>'UserController@postSignUp',
    'as'=>'signup'

]);


Route::post('/signin',[
    'uses'=>'UserController@postSignIn',
    'as'=>'signin'

]);

Route::get('/dashboard',[
    'uses'=>'UserController@getdashboard',
    'as'=>'dashboard'

]);


Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: Make sure Controller.php file exist in App/Http/Controllers/ folder.

Comment: note that `PHP` is case-insensitive for the class naming, but you could use and extend the `\App\Http\Controllers\Controller` instead of just `controller`, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55931755/8740349) for more details

Answer (score 3):

Your name space is wrong for accessing the `Controllers` folder, the first line of the code on the controller file change:

```
namespace App\Controllers;
```

to

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

also change this part in case if you have this error (`Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request as array`):

```
use Request;  to  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

and

```
$email = $request['email'];
$first_name = $request['first_name'];
$password = bcrypt($request['password']);
```

to

```
$email = $request->email;
 $first_name = $request->first_name;
 $password = bcrypt($request->password);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default laravel places controller under

```
app\Http\Controllers
```

therefore, replace `namespace App\Controllers;` by `namespace App\Http\Controllers;`

Edit:

Access the variable of request like following:

```
 $email = $request->input('email');
 $first_name = $request->input('first_name');
 //similar way for other inputs
```

Comment: I already replaced it man,But Now its giving me this error in both registration and login form before registration was working fine.... "Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request as array

Comment: i have changed it as you said now its giving me this error man                        "Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::$email"

Comment: @Charlie_9816, add `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top of your `routes.php` file

Answer (score 0):

The `$request` is an object so you can get the properties with `->`. Change your controller code as below:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers; // HERE

use Illuminate\Http\Request; // FOR YOUR COMMENT
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;
use App\UserTypes;

use Auth;
use Hashids;
use Redirect;
use Request;
use Hash;



class UserController extends controller
{
    public function getdashboard()
    {
        return view('dashboard');
    }

    public function postSignUp(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->email;// HERE
        $first_name = $request->first_name;// HERE
        $password = bcrypt($request->password);// HERE


        $user = new User();
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->first_name = $first_name;
        $user->password = $password;

        $user->save();
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
    public function postSignIn(Request $request)
    {
        if(Auth::attempt([ 'email' => $request->email,'password' => $request->password])){// HERE
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have changed all the things as you said now it's giving me this error bro i can't figure it out what does it mean                                                        "Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::$email"

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please try adding `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top of your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are some `laravel` [usage samples](https://github.com/mschwarzmueller/laravel-basics-youtube/blob/1295312ab4e0b26f839fb161e9aedf9044559422/app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php#L11) which I would like to link here, and there is a class called `Controller` at `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` which you need to use as your base class, but in short, just change your controller namespace from `App\Controllers` into `App\Http\Controllers`, or you could even implement the `Controller` class for your self which could be looking something like below:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class UserController extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function postSignUp(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'first_name' => 'required|max:120',
            'password' => 'required|min:4'
        ]);
        $email = $request['email'];
        $first_name = $request['first_name'];
        $password = bcrypt($request['password']);
        $user = new User();
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->first_name = $first_name;
        $user->password = $password;
        $user->save();
        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
    public function postSignIn(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']])) {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
    public function getLogout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
    public function getAccount()
    {
        return view('account', ['user' => Auth::user()]);
    }
    public function postSaveAccount(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
           'first_name' => 'required|max:120'
        ]);
        $user = Auth::user();
        $old_name = $user->first_name;
        $user->first_name = $request['first_name'];
        $user->update();
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $filename = $request['first_name'] . '-' . $user->id . '.jpg';
        $old_filename = $old_name . '-' . $user->id . '.jpg';
        $update = false;
        if (Storage::disk('local')->has($old_filename)) {
            $old_file = Storage::disk('local')->get($old_filename);
            Storage::disk('local')->put($filename, $old_file);
            $update = true;
        }
        if ($file) {
            Storage::disk('local')->put($filename, File::get($file));
        }
        if ($update && $old_filename !== $filename) {
            Storage::delete($old_filename);
        }
        return redirect()->route('account');
    }
    public function getUserImage($filename)
    {
        $file = Storage::disk('local')->get($filename);
        return new Response($file, 200);
    }
}
```

> Note that `PHP` is case-insensitive for the class naming, but you could use and extend `\App\Http\Controllers\Controller` instead of just `controller`

Comment: PHP may be case-insensitive, but autoloading depends on the sensitivity of the underlying filesystem. If using linux, a class named `controller` will look for `controller.php`. If the file is named `Controller.php`, then the file will not be found. If using Windows, then I believe it would work fine.